# Exclude html element at ko.applyBindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
<div id="model-one-container" data-bind="css: {foo: someModelOneProperty}">
    <div id="model-two-container" data-bind="text: someModelTwoProperty"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: anotherModelOneProperty"></div>
</div>
```

.

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModelOne, document.getElementById("model-one-container"));
ko.applyBindings(viewModelTwo, document.getElementById("model-two-container"));
```

If I do that, knockout will complain that there isn't a "someModelTwoProperty" in viewModelOne, so I need to exclude the #model-two-container div from the first applyBindings.
Is there any way to do this without altering the view-models?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's [the answer](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html).

Since knockout 2.0 there is a controlsDescendantBindings flag which you can use to create a custom binding that then stops KO from binding on an element or any of its children.